# VBScript to send outlook email without asking user to log in

Tags: outlook, vbscript

I made VBScript to send Outlook email without prompt user to log in in his or her account. But when I tried to run the script, it prompts me to log in. I don't  know is it possible to send it without asking, but any help is nice. Here's my code:

```
  'Create an Outlook object
  Dim Outlook 
  Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  
  'Create e new message
  Dim Message 
  Set Message = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  With Message
    .Subject = "subject"
    .Body = "body"
    
    'Set destination email address
    .Recipients.Add ("test@outlook.com")
    
    'Set sender address If specified.
    'Const olOriginator = 0
    'If Len(aFrom) > 0 Then .Recipients.Add(aFrom).Type = olOriginator
    
    'Send the message
    .Send
  End With
```

I'm sorry, the code is so dirty.

PS: I'm not good with English. Please understand if i wrote something wrong.

Comment: Do you mean it prompts you to select an Outlook profile? Or to supply the credentials?

Comment: It prompts to select profile and log into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon) method only to log on to a specific profile when Outlook is not already running. This is because only one Outlook process can run at a time, and that Outlook process uses only one profile and supports only one MAPI session. When users start Outlook a second time, that instance of Outlook runs within the same Outlook process, does not create a new process, and uses the same profile.

If Outlook is already running, using this method does not create a new Outlook session or change the current profile to a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn profile prompt off in Control Panel | Mail | Show Profiles.

Comment: How can i make it programmable?

Comment: Set PickLogonProfile value to 0 in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Exchange\Client\Options

Comment: But how can I do it with VBScript?

Comment: Use WScript.Shell object and call RegWrite. Or use Shell.Application and use ShellExecute to run reg command

Comment: But How?!?!?!?!

Comment: I don't mean to be mean, but literally the first Google hit is https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_registry_wshshell.php